# How can I use jQuery to redirect to another page?

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a log-in form that I want to validate and redirect (if the username and password are correct) with jQuery, and the redirect isn't working.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lc-login').click(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();        

        if (testUser(username) === true && testPass(pass) === true) {            
            window.location.replace("http://www.domain.com/home.html");
        } else {
            alert('warning message');
        }
    });
});
```

I've try replacing the `window.location.replace` with `window.location.href` and still nothing. I should say that the testUser and testPass are working fine, because if I add a simple `alert('the validation is ok!')`, the message is appearing on my screen.